# how to disable traystatus update messages?

Tags: software-update

How to disable [traystatus](https://www.traystatus.com) updates popup ?
this sofware keeps bothering me with update messages and i want it to stop !
i've tried to edit hosts file and block the address www.traystatus.com - but maybe i am not doing it right ?!
please help. 
thank you!

Comment: YOu can trace IP address with Procmon then block.

Comment: Blocking the communication on the executable won't stop the localized notifications from happening.

Comment: so what then ??

Comment: @Ramhound Why not? If it's blocked it won't know if there is a new version available.

Comment: Have you tried asking their support? Even the personal version includes support ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This software keeps bothering me with update messages

Go to "Settings" > "Options" and uncheck "Check for Updates Automatically"

[image]

If this doesn't work then contact [TrayStatus support](https://www.traystatus.com/Support/).

Support is included for all versions (including the Free version):

> [image]

Source [TrayStatus Version Comparison](https://www.traystatus.com/Compare/)

Comment: worked - tnx :)